# How to optimize PostgreSQL JOIN based on time ranges

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization

We have an expensive query that needs to extract daily values from a table storing metrics for objects over timeranges. We have isolated the expensive part of the query and extracted the following minimal example.

Some details on the tables involved:
`history` is defined as

```
create table history
(
    start_ts      timestamp,
    end_ts        timestamp,
    obj_id        integer,
    metrics       jsonb
);


create index idx_history_timerange
    on metrics_history (start_ts, end_ts);

create index idx_history_file_id
    on metrics_history (obj_id);

create index history_full_cover_idx
    on history (obj_id, start_ts, end_ts) include (metrics);
```

`all_objs_per_scope` is a simple m:n relation between `obj_id` and `scope_id`

`history` contains about 6 million rows in total for roughly 600k distinct objects. The timeranges per object do not overlap.

The following is the minimal example query. The dates, the scope_id and the key for the metrics JSON field are user input.

In our testing the query runtime scales roughly linearly with the length of timerange, which might be acceptable if it was faster in general. Ideally this should be fater than 10s for a whole year.

The number of objects in the given scope also affects the runtime, but not as straight forwardly as the length of the given timerange. More on than below.

The given JSON key seems to have no effect on runtime.

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
    WITH timestamp_series AS (
        SELECT series.ts as ts
        FROM generate_series(
            '2022-07-12'::timestamp,
            '2022-08-12'::timestamp,
            '1 day'::interval) AS series(ts)
    )
    SELECT
        ts,
        obj_id,
        COALESCE((metrics ->> '64')::FLOAT, 0) AS value
    FROM timestamp_series
    JOIN history ON history.start_ts <= timestamp_series.ts
    AND history.end_ts > timestamp_series.ts
    AND obj_id IN (SELECT obj_id AS id FROM all_objs_per_scope WHERE scope_id = 87)
    AND history.start_ts <= '2022-08-12'
    AND history.end_ts >= '2022-07-12'
```

There are about 500k obj_ids in the scope with id 87 (reminder that's 500k of 600k total). And for that scope the planner comes up with this query plan:

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|QUERY PLAN                                                                                                                                                                                                          |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|Hash Join  (cost=42119.88..17542416.61 rows=147924810 width=20) (actual time=250.729..13941.074 rows=8985650 loops=1)                                                                                               |
|  Hash Cond: (history.obj_id = all_objs_per_scope.obj_id)                                                                                                                                                |
|  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.43..15942340.50 rows=170863778 width=262) (actual time=0.041..7052.328 rows=8985650 loops=1)                                                                                             |
|        ->  Function Scan on generate_series series  (cost=0.00..10.00 rows=1000 width=8) (actual time=0.010..0.052 rows=32 loops=1)                                                                                |
|        ->  Index Scan using idx_history_timerange on history  (cost=0.43..14233.69 rows=170864 width=270) (actual time=0.024..187.880 rows=280802 loops=32)                                        |
|              Index Cond: ((start_ts <= series.ts) AND (start_ts <= '2022-08-12 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (end_ts > series.ts) AND (end_ts >= '2022-07-12 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))|
|  ->  Hash  (cost=35634.70..35634.70 rows=518779 width=4) (actual time=250.024..250.026 rows=525331 loops=1)                                                                                                        |
|        Buckets: 1048576 (originally 524288)  Batches: 1 (originally 1)  Memory Usage: 26661kB                                                                                                                      |
|        ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on all_objs_per_scope  (cost=7650.97..35634.70 rows=518779 width=4) (actual time=32.684..163.549 rows=525331 loops=1)                                                                 |
|              Recheck Cond: (scope_id = 87)                                                                                                                                                                         |
|              Heap Blocks: exact=21499                                                                                                                                                                              |
|              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on all_objs_per_scope_unique_idx  (cost=0.00..7521.27 rows=518779 width=0) (actual time=29.639..29.640 rows=525331 loops=1)                                                    |
|                    Index Cond: (scope_id = 87)                                                                                                                                                                     |
|Planning Time: 0.399 ms                                                                                                                                                                                             |
|Execution Time: 14250.802 ms                                                                                                                                                                                        |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

A smaller scope with about 160k objects, results in the following plan. The breaking point between which plan is chosen seems to be around 50% of existing objects in the scope. Smaller scopes use the second plan, larger ones the first one.

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|QUERY PLAN                                                                                                                                                                      |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|Nested Loop  (cost=57568.26..7647417.04 rows=44265468 width=20) (actual time=2698.298..2698.302 rows=0 loops=1)                                                                 |
|  Join Filter: ((history.start_ts <= series.ts) AND (history.end_ts > series.ts))                                                                               |
|  ->  Function Scan on generate_series series  (cost=0.00..10.00 rows=1000 width=8) (actual time=0.009..0.014 rows=32 loops=1)                                                  |
|  ->  Materialize  (cost=57568.26..344604.50 rows=398389 width=270) (actual time=84.321..84.321 rows=0 loops=32)                                                                |
|        ->  Hash Join  (cost=57568.26..342612.56 rows=398389 width=270) (actual time=2698.277..2698.279 rows=0 loops=1)                                                         |
|              Hash Cond: (history.obj_id = all_objs_per_scope.obj_id)                                                                                                |
|              ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on history  (cost=29896.69..310904.30 rows=1537774 width=270) (actual time=133.159..471.802 rows=707498 loops=1)                     |
|                    Recheck Cond: ((start_ts <= '2022-08-12 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (end_ts >= '2022-07-12 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))         |
|                    Heap Blocks: exact=238148                                                                                                                                   |
|                    ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_history_timerange  (cost=0.00..29512.24 rows=1537774 width=0) (actual time=75.315..75.315 rows=707498 loops=1)         |
|                          Index Cond: ((start_ts <= '2022-08-12 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (end_ts >= '2022-07-12 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))     |
|              ->  Hash  (cost=25731.06..25731.06 rows=155241 width=4) (actual time=2090.490..2090.492 rows=157424 loops=1)                                                      |
|                    Buckets: 262144  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 7583kB                                                                                                           |
|                    ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on all_objs_per_scope  (cost=2291.55..25731.06 rows=155241 width=4) (actual time=2018.784..2065.120 rows=157424 loops=1)              |
|                          Recheck Cond: (scope_id = 80)                                                                                                                         |
|                          Heap Blocks: exact=15024                                                                                                                              |
|                          ->  Bitmap Index Scan on all_objs_per_scope_unique_idx  (cost=0.00..2252.74 rows=155241 width=0) (actual time=2016.143..2016.143 rows=157424 loops=1)|
|                                Index Cond: (scope_id = 80)                                                                                                                     |
|Planning Time: 0.502 ms                                                                                                                                                         |
|Execution Time: 2699.537 ms                                                                                                                                                     |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

As far as we can tell from the runtimes, the decision by the planner to choose one plan over the other seems reasonable.

Is there anything we can do, including radically restructuring our tables to speed this up?

EDIT: As @jjanes pointed out inthe comments the example for the second query plan was badly chosen as it returns 0 rows. (The particular scope had no data for the given timerange.) I fixed that and here is the new query plan for the same scope. Looks essentially the same with the exception that it does return "a few" rows.

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|QUERY PLAN                                                                                                                                                                          |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|Nested Loop  (cost=74958.41..589737.44 rows=2629659 width=20) (actual time=60.952..5360.037 rows=10326172 loops=1)                                                                  |
|  Join Filter: ((metrics_history.start_ts <= series.ts) AND (metrics_history.end_ts > series.ts))                                                                                   |
|  Rows Removed by Join Filter: 236923                                                                                                                                               |
|  ->  Function Scan on generate_series series  (cost=0.00..10.00 rows=1000 width=8) (actual time=0.009..0.040 rows=31 loops=1)                                                      |
|  ->  Materialize  (cost=74958.41..155891.66 rows=23667 width=270) (actual time=1.966..41.804 rows=340745 loops=31)                                                                 |
|        ->  Gather  (cost=74958.41..155773.33 rows=23667 width=270) (actual time=60.925..521.223 rows=340745 loops=1)                                                               |
|              Workers Planned: 2                                                                                                                                                    |
|              Workers Launched: 2                                                                                                                                                   |
|              ->  Nested Loop  (cost=73958.41..152406.63 rows=9861 width=270) (actual time=56.552..716.250 rows=113582 loops=3)                                                     |
|                    ->  Parallel Bitmap Heap Scan on metrics_history  (cost=73957.98..120719.55 rows=12275 width=270) (actual time=56.483..119.172 rows=165519 loops=3)             |
|                          Recheck Cond: ((start_ts <= '2023-05-12 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (end_ts >= '2023-04-12 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))       |
|                          Heap Blocks: exact=18928                                                                                                                                  |
|                          ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_metrics_history_timerange  (cost=0.00..73950.61 rows=29460 width=0) (actual time=47.164..47.164 rows=496558 loops=1)         |
|                                Index Cond: ((start_ts <= '2023-05-12 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (end_ts >= '2023-04-12 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))   |
|                    ->  Index Only Scan using all_files_per_scope_unique_idx on all_files_per_scope  (cost=0.43..2.58 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.003..0.003 rows=1 loops=496558)|
|                          Index Cond: ((scope_id = 67) AND (file_id = metrics_history.file_id))                                                                                     |
|                          Heap Fetches: 340745                                                                                                                                      |
|Planning Time: 0.416 ms                                                                                                                                                             |
|Execution Time: 5750.332 ms                                                                                                                                                         |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: 1) I would get rid of the CTE and use a [daterange](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html) instead. Something like `daterange(history.start_ts, history.end_ts) <@ daterange('2022-07-12', '2022-08-12')` per [Range operators/functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-range.html). 2) I would turn this ` AND obj_id IN (SELECT obj_id AS id FROM all_objs_per_scope WHERE scope_id = 87)` into a `JOIN` to all_objs_per_scope`.

Comment: @jjanes nice catch. I was so focused on the rest of the plan that I never checked what it actually returned. I'll have to check out what's going on there, as I would actually expect some results.

Comment: @Adrian Klaver can you elaborate why you think that might help? I'm not questioning that it is valid and we will try it, I just want to understand how I would be able to come to that conclusion on my own in the future. I don't see anything in the query plan that would lead me to believe those things are an issue in this particular ase.

Comment: Well you are repeating your self with the CTE and `JOIN history ON history.start_ts <= timestamp_series.ts` and `AND history.start_ts <= '2022-08-12' AND history.end_ts >= '2022-07-12'`. This `AND obj_id IN (SELECT obj_id AS id FROM all_objs_per_scope WHERE scope_id = 87)` seems to me extra work vs a `JOIN`.

Comment: The large gap between the actual time of the hash join and the nested loop is weird, and something I can't reproduce.  What version of PostgreSQL are you using?  And what is your hardware like?

Comment: @jjanes Indeed, I have seen this in multiple plans, so didn't think too much of it. We are running a Flex DB in Azure. I believe the server is currently at 4 cores but we've played around with different available sizings. Postgres version is 13.10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the only reason you are doing the join to the CTE is for it to provide duplicate answers for the history rows which span more than one day.  Rather than generating a month of duplicate entries for every history row and then filtering the wrong ones out, you could just generate the correct duplicates to start with, by calling generate_series once per history row with tailored arguments.

So something like:

```
SELECT
    ts,
    obj_id,
    COALESCE((metrics ->> '64')::FLOAT, 0) AS value
FROM 
   history 
CROSS JOIN 
   generate_series(greatest('2022-07-12',history.start_ts::date+1),least('2022-08-12',end_ts::date),interval '1 day') f(ts)
where obj_id IN (SELECT obj_id AS id FROM all_objs_per_scope WHERE scope_id = 87)
AND history.start_ts <= '2022-08-12'
AND history.end_ts >= '2022-07-12';
```

In my hands this is about twice as fast as your original formulation.  But your original formulation is about 4 times faster for me that what you report, and without knowing why that is the case makes it hard to predict whether you will see the same relative gain, or more, or less.

Comment: We tried something very similar recently and initial results seem to be closer to 10x improvement for our real world query, maybe more. Will be investigating in detail today.  This will likely end up as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could replace the two columns `(start_ts,end_ts)` with a single column of type `tsrange`.  Then build a GiST index on that column, and test it with `<@` rather than with a conjunction of inequalities.

Comment: The daterange suggestion is a common theme in the comments and answers. We actually tried that before and had the impression that the performance improved slightly with the usage of separate end_ts and start_ts. I now wonder if we did something wrong.

Comment: @MattM. was the index used? Could you show a plan for that version of it?

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer as not tested and based on a certain amount of guessing about what you want.

```
SELECT
    history.start_ts,
    obj_id,
    COALESCE((metrics ->> '64')::FLOAT, 0) AS value
FROM
    history
JOIN
    all_objs_per_scope AS aops
ON 
    history.obj_id = aops.obj_id
WHERE 
    scope_id = 87
AND 
    daterange(history.start_ts, history.end_ts) <@ daterange('2022-07-12', '2022-08-12')
```